# Powershell click-to-download Javavascript:__doPostBack

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, powershell

So I've tried both ways in invoking a web and also creating an object with IE inside to use Document method and click a link to download.

$link = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('a') | where-object {$_.innerText -eq 'Windows'}
$link.click()

OR

invoke-webrequest $url|select -exp links |select href | where{$*.href -like “*windows*”}|foreach{start-bitstransfer $* C:\Users\temp

As you can see I've got the whole thing figured out as long as the link I'm clicking on is not a hidden javascript input.

My problem is that I am trying to automate some work with a website that doesn't have the Document method that I can call. Also, when I try extracting the download link, well, here is what it looks like

href

javascript:__doPostBack('ctl05$CPH_Main$rdgReports$ctl00$ctldf$ctl00','')

Is there anyway with PS to click and download that href link?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to go about this is to send keystrokes even though it's bad practice it seems to be the only solution.